# How can I generate textboxes then ng-model their values to expressions in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Right now I have this, where the first section can generate text inputs meant to represent a varying number of items.

```
function itemBtnFunction() {
  var totalItem = document.getElementsByClassName("dymItem");
  totalItem = totalItem.length + 1;
  angular.element(document.querySelector('#divItem')).append("<p id='dymItem" + totalItem + "_wrapperIng'><input type='text' ng-model='itemDestination" + totalItem + "' class='dymItem' id='dymItem" + totalItem + "' placeholder='Item'><input type='button' value='-' onclick=remove_item('dymItem" + totalItem + "');></p>");
}
```

And then a function to remove the generated textboxes. Right now this works well to my knowledge though ID numbers will repeat if textboxes are not deleted in a reverse order which is something I will likely need to address.

```
function remove_item(id) {
  console.log(id + "_wrapperIng");
  document.getElementById(id + "_wrapperIng").outerHTML = "";
  id = null;
}

var app = angular.module("outputApp", []);
```

Right now the app itself is mostly untouched as I'm really only using ng-model on inputs to bind to expressions within a textbox as I show further down. I have a custom filter.

```
app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope) {});
app.filter('round', function() {
  return function(value, mult, dir) {
    dir = dir || 'nearest';
    mult = mult || 1;
    value = !value ? 0 : Number(value);
    if (dir === 'up') {
      return Math.ceil(value / mult) * mult;
    } else if (dir === 'down') {
      return Math.floor(value / mult) * mult;
    } else {
      return Math.round(value / mult) * mult;
    }
  };
});
```

And here we have the inputs that all work as intended, placing the input into the textarea as desired. The generated textboxes however, even with ng-model set to something static such as {{itemDestination}} will not function. Inspecting the element shows that the event is missing from the generated textboxes but is obviously present in the regular txtItem. What I need is for these generated boxes to function and also to create {itemDestinationx}} to match each generated input. Ideally separated by "", and a line break if possible. I tried a couple methods with ng-click but couldn't seem to figure it out. I would guess it has something to do with ng-repeat and arrays but I couldn't find an example that got me anywhere.

```
<input name="txtName" ng-model="nameDestination" type="text">
<input name="txtDate" ng-model="durationDestination" type="date">
<div id="divItem">
  <input name="txtItem" ng-model="itemDestination" type="text">
  <div id="wrapperIng">
  </div>
  <button onclick="itemBtnFunction()">+</button>
</div>


<textarea id="appDestination">
  Name: "{{nameDestination}}", 
  Duration: "{{(durationDestination)}}",
  Item: "{{(durationDestination) % (60 * 60) / 60 | number | round:'':'down'}}H{{(durationDestination) % 60 | number: 0}}M", 
  Item: "{{ itemDestination }}"</textarea>
```

I've tossed this into Plunker as well.
https://plnkr.co/edit/IttC4p?p=info

The final output would hopefully look like this:

```
 Name: "Example", 
 Duration: "1H10M",
 Item: "1",
 Item: "2",
 Item: "3",
```

And so on, as close to original format as possible and in the text area for submission.

Comment: you might want to look into [Angular SchemaForm](http://schemaform.io/) which does something very similar to what you are trying to accomplish;  It generates forms dynamically from a JSON Schema Document.  If it doesn't work for you, the code is open source and you can at least explore how their code works.

Comment: I certainly will, thanks for the suggestion.